# Calculating series with two indices in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I need to calculate series (k/m)^2 with k and m from 1 to 100

`A = Sum(Sum((k/m)**2, (k, 1, 100)),(m,1,100))` - doesn't work

May I do it using only sympy functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [doit()](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.doit) for sums and then `evalf`:

`A = Sum(Sum((k/m)**2, (k, 1, 100)),(m,1,100)).doit().evalf()`

Returns `553196.802627558`